# How to clear asyncfileupload after button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload, asyncfileupload

I'm uploading a file and that works fine but I'm trying to clear the file name from showing after I click on a button.

`<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" OnClientUploadComplete="OutturnImageUpload" OnUploadedComplete="fileUpload_UploadedComplete" accept="image/*" />`

The name stays after I click on choose file button which is fine. I only want to clear the file name after I click the Save Outturn button, so they can upload another file.

[image]

I tried creating a clear function that gets triggered when the button is clicked:

```
$('#btnSaveOutturn').click(function () {
                Clear();
            });

    function Clear() {
        $('#<%= fileUpload.ClientID %>').val("");
    }
```

But that didn't clear the file name. I tried adding `$(sender._element).find('input').val('');` to the `OnClientUploadComplete` but that clears the name as soon as the Choose File button is clicked and it makes it look like no file was uploaded:

[image]

How can I clear the file name only after I click the button?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829571/clearing-an-html-file-upload-field-via-javascript)

Comment: @PrashantShirke none of those examples worked. In that link he was using `input`type but I'm using `ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload `